# Jquery AJAX submission form error

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, expressionengine

I have created a basic submission form using expression engine's plugin free form. From the CMS side of things my data is being submitted into the EE CMS. However after i have submitted my details, rather than receiving a success message i receive the following message on my form `object object`. `<div id="form-messages" class="success">[object Object]</div>`

I am assuming this has something to do with my jquery As the function was working when i was validating the submission through php.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
var form = $('#ajax-contact');
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

$(form).submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var formData = $(form).serialize();

// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData
})
.done(function(response) {
    //  formMessages div has the 'success' class.
    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
    $(formMessages).addClass('success');

    // Set the message text.
    $(formMessages).text(response);

    // Clear the form.
    $('#name').val('');
    $('#email').val('');
})
.fail(function(data) {
    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    $(formMessages).addClass('error');

    // Set the message text.
    if (data.responseText !== '') {
        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    } else {
        $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
    }
});

})
```

HTML

```
<div id="form-messages" class="success"></div>

exp:freeform:form 
            form_id="1"
            admin_notify="me@email.com"
            form:class="main-contact submit-fade ajax-form"
            form:id="ajax-contact"


        }

            <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 hide-form">
               <li>
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  {freeform:field:first_name
                      attr:class="form-control" 
                      attr:placeholder="First Name" 
                      attr:class="required"
                  }

                </li>

                <li>
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  {freeform:field:email
                      attr:class="form-control" 
                      attr:placeholder="Email" 
                      attr:class="required"
                  }
                 </li>
              </ul>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">

        {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: Is the controller returning JSON? It looks like jQuery is parsing the JSON, so `response` is an object, not a string.

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` show?

Comment: Object {success: true, entry_id: 5, form_id: "1", return: "http://mysite/index.php/sandbox/freeform", return_url: "http://mysiteindex.php/sandbox/freeform"}

Comment: @Barmar i am assuming i need to amend .done(function) but i am not 100% sure what to amend it too

Comment: Which part of that do you want to display in `form-messages`?

Comment: @Barmar in the form-messages div should display either be a success message or an error

Comment: There's no success message in the response, just an object property that contains `true` or `false`. I've updated my answer to show how to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is being parsed as JSON. Use:

```
.done(function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
        formMessages.removeClass("error").addClass("success").text("Success!");
        $("#name,#email").val("");
    } else {
        formMessages.removeClass("success").addClass("error").text("Oops, failure!");
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that however it still doesn't work, i have edited my question slightly just to make thing a bit more clear

Comment: Is there also a way I flag errors in the field, i.e if the user enter a unrecognised email address etc

Comment: You could add a `message` field to the JSON response, and display that instead of the hard-coded messages I put in my answer.